# Any way to work around JVM code size limits tripped by large Chisel file

Tags: scala, jvm, chisel, rocket-chip

Just say you were autogenerating some Chisel code for some infrastructure in your chip. A single file instantiating a load of memory mapped registers and then IO assignments.

Then say one day you add an extra register and the JVM goes bang and doesn't want to build it any more because of an aribtrary 64k method limit size in the JVM:

```
[error] Could not write class HasRegsModuleContents because it exceeds JVM code size limits. Method scala/Some's code too large!
[error] one error found
[error] (chipBlocks / Compile / compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 41 s, completed 27/11/2018 2:32:29 AM
```

Inside HasRegsModuleContents is a declaration of a bunch of registers and then a big regmap statement with a bunch of register declarations for the chip. Afterwards is the assignment to or from the module's io port.

This was working very well for us but now appears to be maxxed out which is rather annoying.

Has anyone come across this before? It's going to be work to break this up  into multiple register blocks (and more hardware, having multiple bus interfaces on the pbus now), so would appreciate if anyone knows a way around it.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that same restriction lead to the splitting of the rocket-chip decode tables into [multiple classes](https://github.com/freechipsproject/rocket-chip/blob/3915e15833d18124d5edb1332252d68f968a7c0e/src/main/scala/rocket/IDecode.scala).

Unfortunately I don't think there's an easy workaround since this is a historical design mistake in the JVM itself. I can think of 2 ways to fix the problem, but I think either of them is a bit of work:

1. Have you generator partition the register creation logic into methods
2. Rather than generating Chisel source code, write Chisel itself to generate the necessary registers and related logic

#2 is probably The Right Way™ but #1 might be more approachable given your current infrastructure set up.

Comment: What do mean by "Rather than generating Chisel source code, write Chisel itself to generate the necessary registers and related logic" ? can you elaborate ?

Comment: I'm not sure how familiar you are with hardware generation languages like Chisel, but the basic idea is that you write software that generates your hardware. If you're interested, you can check out my ORConf2018 talk on Chisel and related projects: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4FCZLrauDcE. You can also check out the Chisel bootcamp if you're interested in learning Chisel itself: https://github.com/freechipsproject/chisel-bootcamp

Answer (score 1):

There are several workarounds for this problem.

The reason you get this error is because your method is too huge. Often, the method in question is the constructor, which is the most common case for the problem. Often, the cause is excessive pattern matching (although it's not as big of a problem as it used to be in the past). To make the method smaller, you need to extract some things into separate methods. Therefore replace some

```
val x = (huge expression)
```

with either:

```
def calculate_x = (huge expression)
val x = calculate_x
```

or

```
val x = (() => (huge expression))()
```

or even

```
lazy val x = (huge expression)
```

Pick the one that won't break or unnecessarily slow down your app.

Comment: As a last option you can block-box what  @Karol S refereed as  huge expression.